# How to fix 'cannot reshape array of size 30233088 into shape (1,64,64,3)' error in python?

Tags: python, image, reshape

I convert the image to rgb format after which I want to resize it to the size I'm interested in but the error below appears
I tried the following function:

```
def predict(graph):
    im = Image.open("image.jpeg")
    mat = np.asarray(im.convert('RGB'))  
    mat = mat.reshape(1,64,64,3)
    mat = mat / 255.
    x = graph.get_tensor_by_name("input_x:0")
    outlayer = graph.get_tensor_by_name("outlayer:0")
    prob = graph.get_tensor_by_name("probability:0")
    predict = graph.get_tensor_by_name("predict:0")

    with tf.Session(graph=graph) as sess:
        np.set_printoptions(suppress=True)
        out, prob, pred = sess.run([outlayer, prob,predict],feed_dict={x:mat})
        print(out)
        print(prob)
        print(pred)

if __name__=="__main__":
    graph = load_model()
    predict(graph)
```

but I can not get rid of this error

```
---> 18         mat = mat.reshape(1,64,64,3)
     19         mat = mat / 255.
     20         x = graph.get_tensor_by_name("input_x:0")

ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 30233088 into shape (1,64,64,3)
```

Comment: the reshape dimensions should have the same number of elements as the original dimension. In your case - 64*64*3 != 30233088 and hence the error. In your case you may need to crop the image and then reshape.